# Modal Windows and Div Refresh

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog, refresh, prototypejs

I have a problem with [prototype.js](http://prototypejs.org/) modals and a function for `<div>` refresh.

I try to create some modals by clicking on a link in the top menu. But when the modal function executes, the `<div>` elements just disappear.

Why does this happen?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#presenti").load("presenti.php");
  var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
    $("#presenti").load('presenti.php?randval=' + Math.random());
  }, 5000);
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#sms").load("message.php");
  var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
    $("#sms").load('message.php?randval=' + Math.random());
  }, 10000);
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#lallero");
  var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
    $("#lallero").load(location.href + " #lallero");
  }, 3000);
});
```

WHOLE HTML

```
<html>
```

0) { echo "(".$NonLetti .") Teen Wolf GDR";} else { echo "Teen Wolf GDR"; }?>

```
<table width="100%" height="100%" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>

    <!--  colonna sinistra!-->

            <td style="background-image:url('image/main/pattern_colonna.png');" valign="top">    

                <table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>

                    <tr>

                        <td width="214" height="220" style="background-image:url('img/luoghi/<?= $Immagine ?>');background-repeat:no-repeat;border-bottom:0px solid #0b0b0b;">
                        <div id="info_loc">
                            <a href="javascript: void(0)" onClick="Javascript:window.open('guarda.php?ID=<?= $_SESSION['Stanza'] ?>','look','height=600,width=700,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes')">

                                <img src="image/main/cornice_loc.png" width="214" height="220" class="img_ombra">

                            </a>
                            </div>
                        </td>

                    </tr>   

                    <tr>

                        <td style="height:59px;position: absolute;">

                            <a href="javascript: void(0)" onClick="Javascript:window.open('documentazione.html','doc','height=620,width=840,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes' )">

                                <img src="image/main/doc3.png" class="fade" >

                                </a>

                        </td>


                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                    <? if ((strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== FALSE) OR (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Trident') !== FALSE) OR (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Chrome') !== FALSE) OR (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Opera Mini') !== FALSE) OR (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Opera') !== FALSE) OR (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Safari') !== FALSE)) { ?>
                        <td style="height:69px;position: absolute; top:279px;">
                    <? } elseif (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Firefox') !== FALSE) { ?>
                        <td style="height:69px;position: absolute; top:283px;"><? } ?>

                            <span id="sms" ></span>


                        </td>


                    </tr>
                    <? $Mynoti = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Agenda WHERE Data >= NOW() AND Data <= DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND Creatore = '$Login'");
                       $row = mysql_fetch_array($Mynoti);
                       if ($row['Evento'] != '') {
                   $testolozzo = "Lo Staff ti ricorda che in Data <b>".($row['Data'])."</b> avr&agrave; luogo l'evento <b>".$row['Descrizione']."</b> da te salvato in Agenda. <u>Ulteriori dettagli</u>: ".$row['Evento']."";
                   $testolozzo = mysql_real_escape_string($testolozzo); ?>
                <tr><td style="position: absolute; top:342px; left: 25px" align=center width="180px"><div style="margin:0px auto; padding-top:0px;border:1px solid #1a1a1a;"><a href="messaggioagenda.php" target=palestra><img src="image/main/promemoriaagenda.gif" dynsrc="image/main/promemoriaagenda.gif" loop=infinite></a></div></td></tr> <? } ?>

                    <tr>

                        <td align=center>


                            <div id="presenti">


                            </div>


                        </td>


                    </tr>
```

```
            </td>

    <!--  colonna centrale /frame !-->


       <td style="width:100%;background-image:url('image/main/pattern_colonna.png');" valign=top align=center>

                <div id="lallero"><?php include ('refreshable.php'); ?></div>


                <table style="width:100%;height:95%;" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
                    <tr><td>

                    <!-- qui va l'iframe !-->
                        <? if ($Situazione != "") { ?><div id="news2"><iframe src="situazionechat.php" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="no" scrolling="no" ></iframe></div>
                        <iframe width="100%" height="94%" src="<?= $Link ?>" frameborder="no" name="palestra"></iframe><? } else { ?>
                        <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="<?= $Link ?>" frameborder="no" name="palestra"></iframe><? } ?>
                        </td></tr>
                </table>

            </td>


    <!--  colonna destra!-->

            <td style="background-image:url('image/main/pattern_colonna.png');" valign="top">   

                <table width="200" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>

                    <tr>
                        <?php
                                    $mini = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select mini_avatar from Personaggio where Nome = '".$_SESSION['Login']."'"));
                                ?>
                        <td width="150" height="150" style="background-size: 150px 150px; background-position: center; background-image:url('<?= $mini['mini_avatar'] ?>');background-repeat:no-repeat;border-bottom:0px solid #0b0b0b;">

                            <div id="mini_avatar">

                                <a href="javascript: void(0)" onClick="Javascript:window.open('scheda.php?pg=<?= $Login ?>','look','height=650,width=700,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes')"><img src="image/main/cornice_miniavatar.png" style="margin-left: 24px; margin-top: -2px; width: 152px; height: 152px;"></a>
                            </div>

                        </td>


                    </tr>


                </table>
                <table width="150" height="15px" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 align=center><tr><td align=right>
                <? if ($pg['Dispo'] == '0') { echo "<font famili=Verdana color=#707070 size=2px>Disponibilità attuale:</font> <img src='image/presenti/pallaverde.png' widht=12px height=12px>"; } 
                if ($pg['Dispo'] == '1') { echo "<font famili=Verdana color=#707070 size=2px>Disponibilità attuale:</font> <img src='image/presenti/pallarossa.png' widht=12px height=12px>"; }
                if ($pg['Dispo'] == '2') { echo "<font famili=Verdana color=#707070 size=2px>Disponibilità attuale:</font> <img src='image/presenti/pallagialla.png' widht=12px height=12px>"; }
                if ($pg['Dispo'] == '3') { echo "<font famili=Verdana color=#707070 size=2px>Disponibilità attuale:</font> <img src='image/presenti/pallablu.png' widht=12px height=12px>"; } 
                if ($pg['Dispo'] == '4') { echo "<font famili=Verdana color=#707070 size=2px>Disponibilità attuale:</font> <img src='image/presenti/pallaarancio.png' widht=12px height=12px>"; } 
                if ($pg['Dispo'] == '5') { echo "<font famili=Verdana color=#707070 size=2px>Disponibilità attuale:</font> <img src='image/presenti/pallaviola.png' widht=12px height=12px>"; } ?>
                </td></tr></table>


                <table width="200" style="margin-top:20px" height="25" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>

                    <tr>
                        <td align=center>
                            <div id="tarallo">
                            <a href="javascript: void(0)" onClick="Javascript:window.open('lotteria1.php','lottery','height=650,width=700,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes')" class="menu_top">

                                <img src="image/main/lotteria.png"/>

                            </a>
                        </div>
                        </td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td align=center>
                            <div id="tarallo">
                            <a href="javascript: void(0)" onClick="Javascript:window.open('calendar/index.php','calendar','height=400,width=500,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes')" class="menu_top">

                                <img src="image/main/calendario.png"/>

                            </a>
                        </div>
                        </td>

                    </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <td align=center>
                            <div id="tarallo">
                            <a href="main.php?Dir=77#" target="_top" class="menu_top">

                                <img src="image/main/accoglienza.png"/>

                            </a>
                        </div>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td align=center valign="top">
                        <div id="tarallo"><a href="logout.php" onClick="return Conferma();"target="_top" class="menu_top" name="exit" method=post>
                            <img src="image/main/exit.png" class="tarallo" width=150 height=21 ></a>
                            </div>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>

                        <td colspan="3" align="center">
                            <div id="meteo"><? if ($zonetta =='0') { ?>
                                <? include('meteo.php');?> <? } elseif ($zonetta =='1') { ?><? include('meteot.php');?><? } ?>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>   

                </table>        
        <? $musica=mysql_query("select * from Personaggio where Nome='$Login'");
                          $s=mysql_fetch_array($musica);
                          if (($Musica != "")&&($s['musicachat']==0)) { ?>
                <table width="200" style="margin-top:5px" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
<tr>
                        <td align=center valign=bottom><div style="background-image:url('/image/main/pattern_riquadri.png');margin:0px auto; padding-top:0px;border:1px solid #000;
                        width:160px; height:20px;margin-top:5px;">
                    <iframe src="musicachat.php" width="152" height="20" frameborder="no" scrolling="no" frameborder="1"></iframe>
                    </div></td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>

                        <td align=center>

                                <div style="background-image:url('/image/main/pattern_riquadri.png');margin:0px auto; padding-top:0px;border:1px solid #000;
                                                   width:160px; height:210px;margin-top:10px;">

                                    <iframe src="scroll_news.php" width="160" height="210" frameborder="no" scrolling="no" ></iframe>


                                </div>

                        </td>

                    </tr>

                </table><? } else { ?>

                <table width="200" style="margin-top:5px" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>

                    <tr>

                        <td align=center>

                                <div id="news" >

                                    <iframe src="scroll_news.php" width="160" height="225" frameborder="no" scrolling="no" ></iframe>


                                </div>

                        </td>

                    </tr>

                </table>

                <? } ?>

                <table width="200" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>

                    <tr>

                        <td align=center valign="bottom" align="right">


                        </td>

                    </tr>

                </table>    

            </td>       



</table>
```

Comment: Are you referring to [prototype.js](http://prototypejs.org/)?

Comment: yes, and when i do: when i insert this:

<script type="text/javascript" src="Prototype/javascripts/js.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="Prototype/javascripts/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Prototype/javascripts/effects.js"></script>

and more, div disappear!

Comment: these are the divs: 

<div id="presenti"></div>

<div id="sms"></div>

<div id="lallero"><?php include ('refreshable.php'); ?></div>

Comment: the html code is not a problem. How do i paste it here? It is very long...

Comment: I suggest [editing your post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31884867/edit) to include that information in your question itself. If possible, try to create a short demonstration that shows us your problem.

Comment: edited... hope it helps! :(

Comment: is there any javascript in the pages that are loaded with the `load()` method? The javascript you have attached is jQuery. When the jQuery custom event 'hide' is called it ends up calling the `hide()` method on the element the PrototypeJS adds. That is what is causing the problem. Now you have to find what is calling it.

Comment: I'll check as soon as i get home! Thanks so much, hope is this and that i will be able to fix it! I'll update this later! Thanks again!

Comment: Ok, it didnt work. I mean i need the Hide thing in the modals to do what i have to do (the minimize and maximize options). Is there a way to refresh a div or a span without the "load" method? ç__ç and a div that has a php "include" in it?
I mean there is a way to do this without this code: 
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#presenti").load("presenti.php");
  var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
    $("#presenti").load('presenti.php?randval=' + Math.random());
  }, 5000);
});

and for sms and lallero too...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did it.

I just set this:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

and changed all the $ in the Jquery for the div Refresh with $j.

Thanks everyone! :)